# Viewing & Displaying Memory Usage on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Some apps display the memory usage on your iPhone, which I would like to replicate. They display the memory that your system, apps, etc. occupy. I don't want to know exactly how to do it, just the built-in-methods/functions to use.
*Please use objective-c syntax that is compatible with Xcode 4.6 or later.

Comment: SO isn't a "please write this code for me" forum.  It is geared towards "I tried this and am having problems with that, please help?".   So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

try to use:

[Nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus)
This IOS Framework whose help you to track memory usage. If you open example 'photos' in this framework you can see this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I cannot find this in the Nimbus Framework. Can you be more specific or have a longer answer? Thanks

Comment: run this example which contain nimbus framework: https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/tree/master/examples/photos/NetworkPhotoAlbums

Comment: open nimbus foleder then examples / photos / NetworkPhotoAlbums /

Comment: That link leads me directly to NetworkPhotoAlbums and when I try to open the .xcodeproj it opens to project.pbxproj and then to https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/examples/photos/NetworkPhotoAlbums/NetworkPhotoAlbum.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Comment: you should download nimbus to your computer, then open examples / photos / NetworkPhotoAlbums.